# HTC device adb error

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I couldn't understand why my HTC Wildfire s doesn't recognize by adb. When I run I have this error `insufficient permissions for device` . My platform is ubuntu 12.04. So when I turn into another OS (like MaC os) it is working fine (device runs well enough). So when I turn it on ubuntu it doesn't work.

I read some posts where they said you have to kill you server and start it again. I did it too. but no result

Could anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've manually changed your permissions around on your machine, you need to run your adb server as root to give it permissions to communicate with the Android device.

```
sudo adb start-server
```

[See an article here how to automate it on machine startup](http://www.hrupin.com/2012/01/how-to-start-android-adb-server-on-startup-in-ubuntu-linux-from-root).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to connect to the android device, the Windows needs you to install the driver for the phone, Mac doesn't need you to do anything, Ubuntu needs you to configure a **udev** rules file.
This is the [**link**](https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and I think it may help you.